# rasberry pi capture resize results in rounded up dimensions - how do i slice the result using numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to do a video capture in rasberry pi, requesting a specific width and height of 300x300.

Here is my code:

```
  # Open image.
  with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
    camera.resolution = (640, 480)
    camera.framerate = 30

    camera.start_preview()

    try:
      stream = io.BytesIO()
      for foo in camera.capture_continuous(stream,
              format='rgb',
              use_video_port=True,
              resize=(300, 300)):
        stream.truncate()
        stream.seek(0)
        input = np.frombuffer(stream.getvalue(), dtype=np.uint8)
```

However, when this code is run I get a warning message:

> /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/encoders.py:544:
>   PiCameraResolutionRounded: frame size rounded up from 300x300 to
>   320x304   width, height, fwidth, fheight)))

The resulting tensor is in 1d, and I need it as a 1d for the remainder of the code.

How can I resize this 1d tensor to 3d, slice it to 300x300 then flatten it back to 1d?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this can help you

```
import numpy as np
# This is your iamge, for example.
example_image = np.array([1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3])  
print(example_image)
# this is gonna be the same image but in other shape
example_image = np.reshape(example_image,(3,3)) 
print(example_image)
```

> This code do this:

```
# first print
[1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3]
# second print
[[1 1 1]
 [2 2 2]
 [3 3 3]]
```

ok lets try whit some non squared matrix like this:

```
import numpy as np
# This is your iamge, for example.
example_image = np.array([1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3])  
print(example_image)
# this is gonna be the same image but in other shape
# 3 Row, 4 Columns
example_image = np.reshape(example_image,(3,4)) 
print(example_image,"\n")
# or maybe this...
example_image = np.array([1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3])  
# 3 layers, 2 Row, 2 Columns
example_image = np.reshape(example_image,(3,2,2))   
print(example_image[0], "\n\n" ,example_image[1], "\n\n" ,example_image[2])
```

> Results:

```
#original
[1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3]

#First reshape
[[1 1 1 1]
 [2 2 2 2]
 [3 3 3 3]] 

# Second Reshape
[[1 1]
 [1 1]] 

 [[2 2]
 [2 2]] 

 [[3 3]
 [3 3]]
```

Comment: thanks, this would be clearer with something non 3x3 as its confusing what the 3rd dimension is.  Could you please update with lets say a 4x5 image?

Comment: @OvedD Check again the answer.